# Click function is working when clicking different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div called `appendDiv` and when i click it, a div with class name `textGroup` is appended.

```
$("#appendDiv").on("click", function(e) {

    $('#appendDiv').append("<label class='textGroup' style='width:50px;height:50px;background-color:gray;z-index:4;position:absolute;top:" + e.pageY + "px;left:" + e.pageX + "px;'></label>")

});
```

I have a click function for `textGroup` div (i.e.,) when clicking it, an alert will come. But when i click the `textGroup` div, the alert is coming and a div is appended. This is the function

```
$("#appendDiv").on("click", function(e) {
   $('#appendDiv').append("<label class='textGroup' style='width:50px;height:50px;background-color:gray;z-index:4;position:absolute;top:" + e.pageY + "px;left:" + e.pageX + "px;'></label>")

   $(".textGroup").bind("click", function() {
      alert("appended");
   });
});
```

I know `textGroup` is the child of `appendDiv` . But, my question is

1. I am clicking the `textGroup` div, but why the click function of `appendDiv` is executed?
2. How to restrict the click function of `appendDiv` only when clicking on the `appendDiv` and not on clicking the `textGroup`?

This is the [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/6792vqpb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issue in your code

1) Multiple event binding on elements.

2) event propagation to child click element

Modify the click handler to attach event to last appended element along with stopping of event propagation from parent element:

```
$("#appendDiv .textGroup:last").click( function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("hi")
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g4fq26py/)**

Comment: @Thinker: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this 2 changes:

```
$("#appendDiv").on("click", function(e) {

 $('#appendDiv').append("<label class='textGroup' style='width:50px;height:50px;background-color:gray;z-index:4;position:absolute;top:" + e.pageY + "px;left:" + e.pageX + "px;'></label>")

   // remove .textGroup click event from here
});
```

create new event for textGroup

```
$(document).on("click",".textGroup", function() {
      alert("appended");
});
```

Comment: use `$(this)` rather than querying DOM again

Comment: But still after an alert, a div is appended :(

Answer (score 0):

Events usually bubble up the DOM tree (the label is inside #appenDiv so a "parent" and gets the click event too). To stop it use:

```
$(".textGroup").on("click", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Better way by using on() with chaining like,

```
 $("#appendDiv").on('click',function(e){
        $('#appendDiv').append("<label class='textGroup' style='width:50px;height:50px;background-color:gray;z-index:4;position:absolute;top:" + e.pageY + "px;left:" + e.pageX + "px;'></label>")
 }).on('click','.textGroup',function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("appended");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is due to event bubbling so parent event is triggering before child and then child event is triggering. 
You may use **event.stopPropagation()** with child event. will resolve your problem.